# SQL query to intersect

Tags: sql, intersect

I'm having a lot of issues with SQL, I'm not sure how to do what I need, but the series of steps is this:

Have two tables. 
Table 1 has a 'game_id'

Table 2 has a 'game_id' and 'id' 
 Where 'game_id' is the same as the first table.

Table 1 is a list of games. 
Table 2 is a list of franchises.

I'm trying to make a sql query that will ONLY show the games from a franchise.

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM gamedata_similar_games
INNER JOIN gamedata_franchises
ON gamedata_franchises.id='244'
WHERE gamedata_similar_games.game_id= '6959'
```

But it returns 335 results.  The game is in a franchise with 6 games in it.

Is this too unclear?

Comment: Try researching about the purpose of joins. That will help you a lot, not only with this particular query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the related fields on the ON clause

```
SELECT * FROM gamedata_similar_games G
INNER JOIN gamedata_franchises F
ON G.game_id = F.game_id 
WHERE F.id= '244'
```

Comment: This particular query doesn't seem to yield results I'm expecting. 

It returns 203

I only expect 6 rows.

Comment: Have yo tried running separater querys first ? I mean, SELECT * FROM gamedata_franchises WHERE id = '244', how many records are ?... and SELECT * FROM gamedata_similar_games WHERE game_id IN (SELECT game_id FROM gamedata_franchises WHERE id = '244') ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM gamedata_similar_games WHERE game_id IN (SELECT game_id FROM gamedata_franchises WHERE id = '244') Yields 6 results. 


SELECT * FROM gamedata_similar_games WHERE game_id IN (SELECT game_id FROM gamedata_franchises WHERE id = '244') = 6959
Yields nothing.  

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Why do you say tha still no go ?

Comment: But I think I see why it should be working, but can't understand why I'm not seeing the right results.

Comment: First, how many records the query SELECT * FROM gamedata_franchises WHERE id = '244', then if it's true what you say, run this SELECT * FROM gamedata_similar_games WHERE game_id IN (EACH ID RETURNED IN YOUR FIRST QUERY)